# Failure do not show up in github pull request using SonarQube 6., mvn 3, sonar-maven-plugin:3.2, and Github plugin

Tags: github, sonarqube

I'm using sonarqube 6.2, mvn 3.2.5 to kick off an anlysis of a javascript project but the issues reported by the analysis do not show up in my github pull request.

```
mvn -X -V -f pom-ui.xml -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarqubeaddres:9000 -Dsonar.sources=./src clean sonar:sonar   -Dsonar.issuesReport.console.enable=true -Dsonar.github.repository=reponame -Dsonar.github.pullRequest=1977 -Dsonar.github.oauth=key  -Dsonar.analysis.mode=issues -Dsonar.verbose=true

.....

-------------  Issues Report  -------------

    +27793 issues

      +309 blocker
     +8776 critical
     +8590 major
    +10074 minor
       +44 info

-------------------------------------------


[INFO] 13:53:26.191 ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
[DEBUG] 13:53:26.195 Post-jobs : GitHub Pull Request Issue Publisher (wrapped)
[INFO] 13:53:26.195 Executing post-job GitHub Pull Request Issue Publisher (wrapped)
```

Now I'm watching my pull request #1977 in github as mvn runs the sonar:sonar target and the text changes while the analysis is happening to say "SonarQube analysis in progress". But after the analysis it never reports the issues in the pullrequest. When mvn finished the sonarqube check in the pull request goes back to the text: "sonarqube — SonarQube reported no issues" and clearly there are issues and clearly because the text changes all the security must be set up correct otherwise the message wouldn't ever get updated dynamically as I see it happening as the analysis is being performed.

I also tried preview ... same behavior.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said

> I also tried preview ... same behavior

Presumably you mean that you tried `sonar.analysis.mode=preview` (it's not entirely clear). This is the correct value to use.

Since your permissions seem to be set up correctly, it must be the case that there are no *new* issues in *the code changed in the PR*.

As a side note, `sonar.issuesReport.console.enable=true` is extraneous.

Comment: @MikeGreco for a new question you should... start a new SO question. And screenshots wouldn't hurt. :)

Comment: Also @MikeGreco, if my answer helped you, you might accept it. :)